# Calculating percentage in SQL using partition and join statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to calculate the percent for FinanceClassification per Organization:

[image: Table Data]

So:

```
PRO For Organization 1 = 14/22.5*100  =62.22%
SFC For Organization 1 = 8.5/22.5*100 =37.78% 

PRO For Organization 2 = 84/126*100 = 66.67% 
SFC For Organization 2 = 42/126*100 = 33.33%
```

I need to calculating percentage in SQL using partition and join statement, without CTE. I need to show the results as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOeab.png)

Comment: Would you be able to post your question, sample data, and intended results as text in the question, rather than as an image? This [ASCII Tables tool](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) really helps.

Comment: Also, I'd like to see what you've tried so far and what has or has not worked from those attempts

Answer (score 0):

Your columns are rather hard to read and type, so I'll just use `c1`, `c2`, and `c3`.

```
select t.*,
       c1 * 100.0 / sum(c1) over (partition by c3) as percentage
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    Select Organization,FinanceClassification
, HoursOT/Sum(HoursOT)Over (Partition By Organization)*100.0. as [Percentage]
    from Table
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following query

```
select t1.HourseOT / (select sum(HourseOT) from mytable t2 where t2.OrganizationId = t1.OrganizationId) * 100.0 as percentage,
       t1.FinanceClassificationName,
       t1.OrganizationId
from mytable t1
```

or

```
select t1.HourseOT / t2.sumOfOrganizationId * 100.0 as percentage,t1.FinanceClassificationName,t1.OrganizationId
from mytable t1 
join
  (select OrganizationId,sum(HourseOT) as sumOfOrganizationId
  from mytable
  group by OrganizationId) t2 
on t1.OrganizationId = t2.OrganizationId
```

demo in [*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=794745e39581866addffb842605a4d2a)